# Delete "rubbish" question

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-delete

I wonder how to get rid of questions which are obviously rubbish. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613672/how-to-write-an-uml-for-c-from-a-given-text) where people just dump their homework to be done by someone else. Those question won't help anyone at no time (except you get the same lesson per incidence). Sometimes I notice a "delete" flag, but I have no idea how to set that initially. The general "flag" field only offers *spam*, *rude or abusive* and *in need of moderator intervention*.

Comment: With your reputation, you can already vote to delete it. Gathering two more folks to do the same is possible.

Comment: @E_net4fixesyourmistakes I also thought I've seen that. But there's no "vote do delete" yet on this question. What am I missing?

Comment: Ahh. Maybe I was too much in a rush. Now the flag appeared. Is there some time limit?

Comment: If memory doesn't fail me, users with at least 20k reputation can vote to delete closed questions with a score of -3 or lower.

Comment: I see. That's it. Got down to -5 meanwhile :-)

Comment: The question is already closed. There is no hurry in deleting it. Without anyone taking action it would have been deleted by roomba in a few days.

Comment: @yivi but then it is important to also cast a downvote. Because with a score of 0 it will take 30 days. When i arrived at that question it lacked downvotes.

Comment: @rene You won't get disagreement from me by saying that it's important to downvote. I'm a grumpy monkey.

Comment: @rene But closed questions are deleted in 10 days, even if with score 0, right? (https://imgur.com/a/RBM3E6e)

Comment: @yivi I didn't fancy reading the roomba criteria again. But yes, zero score would work. We have to assume no pity votes come in for 9 days ..

Comment: The legendary Jon Skeet came along to help you.

Comment: @RobertColumbia It does. Finding the right answer to your question is not always easy (why has the accepted answer only one upvote and the question itself is down voted; that's some kind of strangeness lurking around here at meta). Anyway I accept the answer below.... (P.S. down vote for my question just the same. No fun place here)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, downvote the question and flag/vote to close it if you haven't already.  This brings the question further along the path to deletion.

If you have [at least 10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you can vote to delete the question (by clicking the "delete" link below it) once it has been closed for 2 days.  If you  have [at least 20k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you can vote to delete a closed question immediately if it has a score of -3 or lower.  If the question does not fulfil those criteria, the "delete" link doesn't appear.

If the question is closed and has a zero or negative score, it may be [automatically deleted by the Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) after 10 days, subject to various conditions.